# PowerShell: How to create a device in SCCM 2012?

Tags: c#, powershell, sccm, winpe

I have the need to create an SCCM object/device from a running WinPE medium using PowerShell. How could one do such a thing?

A former employee of the company I am working for has created a C# Web Solution using "microsoft.configurationmanagement.managementprovider.dll" to create SCCM devices and add attributes to it. I have to migrate this function to a PowerShell Script running on WinPE.

Any input, pointers on this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could something like this:

```
# client data
$clientname = "PC01"
$mac = "00:11:22:33:44:55"

# server data
$serverhostname = "SCCMSERVER01"
$sitecode = "ABC"
$collname = "Windows_7_OSD"

# query
$collquery = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\SMS\Site_$sitecode" -Class SMS_Collection -Filter "Name='$collname'"

# create computer
$wmiconnection = ([WMIClass]"\\$serverhostname\root\SMS\Site_$sitecode:SMS_Site")
$newclient = $wmiconnection.psbase.GetMethodParameters("ImportMachineEntry")
$newclient.MACAddress = $mac
$newclient.NetbiosName = $clientname
$newclient.OverwriteExistingRecord = $true
$res = $wmiconnection.psbase.InvokeMethod("ImportMachineEntry",$newclient,$null)

# add client to collection
$newmembership = ([WMIClass]"\\$serverhostname\root\SMS\Site_$sitecode:SMS_CollectionRuleDirect").CreateInstance()
$newmembership.ResourceClassName = "SMS_R_SYSTEM"
$newmembership.ResourceID = $res.ResourceID
$newmembership.Rulename = $clientname

$collquery.AddMemberShipRule($newmembership)
```